# Strange behaviour in javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Considering code snippet below,

```
function one(){
    var prm = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    });
    prm.customKey = function(){
    }
    return prm;
}
function two(){
    return one().then(function(){
        //something
    });
}
```

Now calling the function two, returns a promise in which 'customKey' is missing

```
function three(){
    return one();
}
```

But while doing the same thing in function three(without handling success using 'then'), 
returns a promise which has 'customKey' in it.

Can someone clarify me whats really happening and why?

Comment: Whenever you call `.then`, you create a *new* `Promise`. They're not the same object.

Comment: Indeed to do otherwise would violate their semantics, consider: `foo=Promise.resolve(3);bar=foo.then(x => x + 1);foo.then(console.log);` should still log 3, which it couldn't do if `foo===bar`.

Comment: with `prm.customKey = function(){}` you are actually reassigning the value of prm, and there is no promise anymore. #edit Nevermind didn't know that Promise is an object.

Comment: @Deda that's not true: assigning an object property doesn't change the lexical binding of the object.

Comment: @Deda No, you're just creating a new property on the promise object.

Comment: you could extend Promise `class MyPromise extends Promise{  customKey(){ ... } }` and use it as `MyPromise.resove(21).then(v => v*2).customKey()`

Comment: @Deda in JavaScript pretty much everything is an object. If it's not a primitive - boolean, numeric, string, symbol, undefined, or null. Everything but the last two also has an object type that can wrap around it, which is how calling methods on a primitive string works, for example `"abc".toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from "Mozilla Docs" `then` method returns new `Promise` (e.g: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

If you want to assign a function to retrieve / do something in resolve function do it like this:

```
var prm = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let customKeyFunction = () => {
        console.log("I'm custom key function.");
    };

    resolve(customKeyFunction);
})
```

From now on you can call this function like that:

```
function two() {
    return one().then(customKey => {
        customKey();
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i want to get that customKeyFunction before resolving the promise.

I solved this by doing as follows
    `function two(){  
       var prm = one();  
       one.then(function(originalRes){  
             ......  
             resolve(changedRes);  
       });  
       return one;  
    }`  
But now facing another problem. 
`two.then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
});`

two is being resolved with originalRes, while i actually resolved it with changedRes